# Сравнительный ли оборот? Часть ли сказуемого?

Tags: пунктуация

Рассказывает сафари-бой из племени масаи:

> «У меня нет деревни. Только одна жена. Больше мне не дают, ведь я не
>   как все. А живём мы здесь, на территории фермы, – в пятнадцати
>   километрах, это совсем недалеко, поэтому я могу ходить туда обедать.
>   Пообедаю и потом снова вернусь. ***Я же не могу есть, как белые!*** –
>   Он опять расхохотался. – Я молоко пью и кровь. – Откуда-то в его руках
>   возникла белая щепочка, он засунул её в рот и сладко пососал. – Но
>   если у меня будут ещё коровы, я тогда буду богатый и тогда, может
>   быть, будет ещё жена», – он мечтательно улыбнулся.

Другой фрагмент:

> Мне хотелось заглянуть в судьбу человека, который так дорого заплатил
>   за свой английский – по сути, изгнанием из племени. ***Бритая голова,
>   как знак вечной потери,*** и сто километров в день, потому что
>   невозможно разделить трапезу с белыми…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Часть сказуемого: Я же не могу есть **как белые**! Нет паузы, ударение на обороте.

2) Бритая голова, **как знак вечной потери**, и сто километров в день, потому что невозможно разделить трапезу с белыми.

Оборот имеет значение дополнительного уточнения, поэтому обособляется.